# Is $e^{u/2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi n^{2}e^{2u}}$ even?

Tags: riemann-zeta

In this paper: "[ON A RESULT OF G.PÓLYA CONCERNING THE RIEMANN $\xi - FUNCTION$ by DENNIS A. HEJHAL](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02789198)"

the author defines

$$
\theta(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi n^{2} x}
$$
then he says, in the begining of the second page: "**Since $e^{u/2} \theta(e^{2u})$" is even, so is ...**"

I Can't seen why $e^{u/2} \theta(e^{2u})$ is even. He is saying that the following function is even

$$e^{u/2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\pi n^{2}e^{2u}}$$

I used mathematica and got the following result
[image: Imege plot]

Clearly this is not even. Certainly I'm missing something obvious, or is this a typo? If so what should have been written?

Thanks.

---

After the remark of Professor Vetor, I produced computations with more terms, and indeed it seems that it is even. Amazing!!
[image]

Comment: If you have a link to the paper that would be useful - I don't see it on the arxiv offhand...

Comment: That's an artifact: for negative $u$, your series doesn't converge rapidly enough, summing form $-1024$ to $1024$ is not accurate enough. It's a special property of that function based on the Poison summation formula, it can also be used to prove the famous functional equation of the zeta function.

Comment: @ProfessorVector, could you produce a proof of this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: This is a special case of Jacobi identities for theta functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_identities See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Relation_to_the_Riemann_zeta_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is the use of $\theta$ for the function. This is a variant of a Jacobi theta function. More precisely, $\;\theta(x)=\theta_3(0,e^{-\pi x}).\;$ By the transformation properties of $\theta_3$ we have $\theta(x)=\theta(1/x)/\sqrt{x},\;$ and combined with $\;e^{-u}=1/e^u,\;\sqrt{e^u}=e^{u/2},\;$ the even property follows.